# iOS keyboard suggests an old email address

Tags: ios, keyboard, email

I'm running iOS 13.4.1 on an iPad Air 2. When I click on an email form field in Safari, the keyboard suggests two email addresses, one labeled "home" and one labeled "email". The "home" address is the address I use for my Apple ID, but the "email" address is an old email address that I haven't used in over ten years. How did iOS find this email address, and how can I get rid of it?

The old email address still forwards to my main email address, so it's possible that iOS extracted it from my mail, but I have other email addresses that forward to my main address that it doesn't suggest. I couldn't find anything in my iCloud account that's linked to the old address, and I didn't own any Apple products ten years ago. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have this in your contact card. What exactly is your question? Do you need help removing it?

Comment: The question was at the end of the first paragraph: "How did iOS find this email address, and how can I get rid of it?", but I suppose that's StackExchange for you. Thanks for your help; I was looking in keyboard settings and iCloud settings; I suppose iOS must have imported old contact information when I set it up.

Comment: You can go to contacts and look at your contact card (The big one at the top). If that email labeled "email" is there in your contact card, then that's where iOS got it from.

Comment: Hi Robert and @Todd - just a friendly reminder - answers belong in the answer section. Todd I think you have the totally correct answer and can help people if you put it below.

Comment: @bmike Thank you. I do remember that. I wasn't sure if this was correct so I put it in the comments. I will surely add an answer.

Comment: Also - not sure why someone -1 this - not knowing how things work and getting comments and answers means it's a good question IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS gets your email addresses and other accounts from two places. The first place is your Contact Card in Contacts. The second is from your Accounts and Passwords settings in the Settings app. In your specific case, go to your Contact card and see if the email with the label "email" is there. If so then iOS got it from there. You can also check in Settings under the Accounts and Passwords section. These are the only two places it could have come from (maybe iCloud Keychain but probably not). Hope this helps!

Comment: I second this - iOS doesn't extract anything from your mail / documents, but it does watch for settings on other devices and iCloud sync where you identify an account you control

Comment: What if these email are old email addresses (passively still active) that you'd like to keep for a single identity, so they have the label **old** or **obsolete**. The idea would be to make the keyboard suggest the current one.